# Output of a Nested for Loop - Python

Tags: python, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get the output of a nested *for* loop into an array or matrix. For instance, in the code example below, I want to have a (3 by 2)-matrix of the form:

```
[[5 6],
 [6 7],
 [7 8]]
```

But my code is giving out of bound error.

```
import numpy as np

num = [1,2,3]
sep = [4, 5]
M = np.zeros((3,2))
for i in num:
    for j in sep:
        M[i, j] = i + j
M
```

However, I realized that changing the initialization to `np.zeros((4,6))` seems to work but with some irrelevant cells. Can someone explain how this works or possibly how I can achieve this (3 by 2)-matrix.[image: Nested_Loop]

Comment: `for j in sep:` with `sep = [4, 5]` results in that `j` becomes `4` in first iteration and `5` in second. So, this results in `M[i, 4]` or `M[i, 5]` which is an out of bound access for a 3x2 matrix, isn't it. Somehow, you confused the iteration "index" with the value picked from given list in iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the values in your `num` and `sep` lists as indexes. You need to use indexes instead:

```py
import numpy as np

num = [1,2,3]
sep = [4, 5]
M = np.zeros((3,2))
for i_i,i in enumerate(num):
    for i_j,j in enumerate(sep):
        M[i_i, i_j] = i + j

print(M)
```

Output as required.